# ionic v4 naviagation bug

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I have a custom ErrorHandler, that navigate to login page when http response status is 401 or 403.
When navgateByUrl gets called  i can see the login Page but i cant interact with it.

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TOKEN_NAME } from '../../api.config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error) {
    console.error(error);
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    const storage = this.injector.get(Storage);
    if(error === '401' || '403') {
        router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        storage.remove(TOKEN_NAME);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using navigate() method.

```
router.navigate(['/login']);
```